# Is $cos(\bar z)$ analytic anywhere on complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $\cos(\bar z)$ analytic anywhere on complex plane ?

This is my solution

$d(\cos(\bar z))/dz = d(\cos(\bar z))/d(\bar z) \times d(\bar z)/dz = -\sin(\bar z) \times \lim_{\Delta z\to 0} (\Delta \bar z)/(\Delta z)$

Since $(\Delta \bar z)/(\Delta z)$ is not consistent, thus, $d( \cos(\bar z))/dz = 0$

Something like this, Could anybody please help me to continue solving this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Why my thread is not shown in mathematical symbol ?

Comment: If you have an open subset $U\subset \Bbb C$, then your function can't be analytic on $U$. You can just check that it can't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Show Cauchy - Riemann equations are satisfied and both partial derivatives are continuous

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(\bar z)=\cos(x-iy)=\cos x\cosh y+i\sin x\sinh y=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.

Show, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Also show that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ both are continuous.